# How does OpenSSL/Mozilla NSS RSA sign and verify (PK11_Sign, PK11_Verify, PK11_VerifyRecover functions) work?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa, mozilla, nss

I have my RSA public and private keys (all of p,q,e,n,d) in PEM format. I am curious to know:

- How `PK11_Sign()`, `PK11_Verify()` and `PK11_VerifyRecover()` (*from OpenSSL/Mozilla NSS library*) work with RSA?
- How the padding is applied to the input message to be signed?

The context of my question is: I have seen PK11_Sign() adds some padding to my input data during signing. For example (given the key size is 162 bits):

```
my input = 31323334353036373839
padded input = 1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0031323334353036373839
```

I would like to know:

- What is the name of this padding scheme and pointers on how it works?
- What is the default padding scheme for the above mentioned OpenSSL functions? For example, if I perform " `openssl rsautl -in input.txt -inkey mykey.pem -out signed.txt` ", which padding scheme will be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `PK11_Sign` etc. uses PKCS#1 v.1.5 signatures, which includes the padding you mention.
- The padding scheme is part of the algorithm called EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCODE. I do not believe it has a name, although it might be informally called "PKCS#1 v.1.5 signature padding". It is defined in [the PKCS#1 standard](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf).
- According to [the documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html) the default for `openssl rsautl` is to use PKCS#1 v.1.5 signature, which implies this padding.